# using a function to call a class in a while loop

Tags: python, function, class, oop

I'm currently writing a python gui that will ultimately generate a random village for use in tabletop RPG (mainly dungeons and dragons)

I have the code below that will generate a number of taverns based on how big a town the user wants and so far it works fine. I hope the GUI will eventually create shops, temples and other buildings too.

```
class NPC: 
    def __init__(self, first, last):
        self.first = first
        self.last = last
        self.name = first + ' ' + last

class Tavern: 
    def  __init__(self, name1, name2):
        self.name1 = name1
        self.name2 = name2
        self.name = 'The ' + name1 + ' ' + name2

while num_tav != 0:
    morf = random.randint(1, 2)
    if morf == 1: 
        sex = 'male'
    else:
        sex = 'female' 
    first = open(set_race + '_' + sex + '.txt')
    name1 = first.readlines()
    first = random.choice(name1).strip()

    last = open(set_race + '_surnames.txt')
    name2 = last.readlines()
    last = random.choice(name2).strip()

    npcname = NPC(first, last)

    tavern1 = open('tavnames1.txt')
    name1 = tavern1.readlines()
    name1 = random.choice(name1).strip()

    tavern2 = open('tavnames2.txt')
    name2 = tavern2.readlines()
    name2 = random.choice(name2).strip()
    tavern = Tavern(name1, name2)
    print('Taverns/Inns: ' + tavern.name + "The inkeeper is a tall " + set_race + ' ' + sex + " named " + npcname.name + '\n')
    num_tav = num_tav - 1

    w.insert(END, not_b + 'Taverns/Inns: ' + tavern.name + "The inkeeper is a tall " + set_race + ' ' + sex + " named " + npcname.name + '\n' + 'Population is approx. ' + str(population) + ' people\n')
```

The NPC class basically genreates a random name and I'd like to use this in other areas (shops, markets, blacksmith, etc.), not just to generate the name of an innkeeper.

My question is;

Is it possible to create a function that will use the script

```
first = open(set_race + '_' + sex + '.txt')
name1 = first.readlines()
first = random.choice(name1).strip()

last = open(set_race + '_surnames.txt')
name2 = last.readlines()
last = random.choice(name2).strip()

npcname = NPC(first, last)
```

as a function that will call the NPC class, and then just have other while loops calls it? Instead of having the same code repeated in each of the loops I'll use to generate other buildings?

I'm assuming so but I just don't know what it would be called so any help is appreciated.

Comment: yep, sorry a mistake in copying and pasting into the "code" format.

Comment: FIxed, sorry for that.

Answer (score 0):

define the while loop in a function with maybe an extra parameter that gets the type of entity that it is supposed to generate (Tavern, shop,...) and then put it in another python file and import it. as a module.

```
def mynewfunction(set_race,sex):
    first = open(set_race + '_' + sex + '.txt')
    name1 = first.readlines()
    first = random.choice(name1).strip()

    last = open(set_race + '_surnames.txt')
    name2 = last.readlines()
    last = random.choice(name2).strip()


    return NPC(first, last)
```

Then:

```
while (x,y,z):
    npcname = mynewfunction(set_race):
```

Comment: that's more of a comment than answer. Could you exand and explain the answer?

Comment: Yes, I don't have commenting privileges yet :)